# Asp.net mvc [Authorize] attribute will return http 302 instead of http 401 if the authorization fail

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I have created a new asp.net mvc 5 web application and I use individual accounts (form authentication) authentication. this will build a full Account controller.
Then I created a new controller named People , and I add [Authorize] attribute before it as follow:-

```
 [Authorize]
    public class PeopleController : Controller
    {
```

Then I try to directly access the controller without login, so I was redirected to the login page. But what I have noticed is that using IE F12 developer tool, the http status will be 302 and not 401 , although according to http standards if the request fail authentication then the application should return http 401, this what I get:-

[image]

Can anyone advice on this? I mean should any application be fully compliance with the http standards? Or there is no problem of redirecting users to login page if the user is not authenticated without raising an http 401 error (as the default asp.net mvc is doing)?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Returning 302 or 401 http status code in this case depends on if you want to control what happens when the user is unauthorized from the server side or the client side. It also depends on whether the request you made was a full page submit or an AJAX request. AJAX style requests typically prefer 401 while full page submits prefer 302 redirection.

If you want handle the unauthorized case on the server side and redirect the user back to login page, then the common practice is to return a 302 redirection to that page.

If you want to handle this case on the client side, then you can have the request return 401. Then, you will have a 401 handler in the client which will detect it and do a client side redirect to the login page. 401 is also the way to do it if instead of redirection, you want to show a message on the same page that the user is no longer authorized.

You will see Web API Authorize attribute return 401 and MVC Authorize attribute do a 302 redirect.

Comment: so the question is why we have two different approaches as you mentioned "You will see Web API Authorize attribute return 401 and MVC Authorize attribute do a 302 redirect."??

Comment: also inside the default scafolding code generated by asp.net mvc you will find something such as if (country == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            } . so if an object is not found they will return HttpNotFound instead of redirecting to a view, as they do for redirecting to login view.. so not sure what is the rule the govern this ?

Comment: So how do you acualy make it reutn a 401 (as it should) instead of rewriting it as a 302?

Answer (score 0):

302 is a pretty common way to do url redirection. It would be the url redirect that is causing the 302 rather than a 401 error. It indicates that it has moved you from /people/ back to /Account/Login in your case.

Comment: yes i know that 302 means redirect. but will it be more formal to return 401 , and then handle all http 401 to redirect to "account/login/" ?? and is the default behavior breaks the http standards ?